# form will not submit in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to get a form to submit with javascript in innerHTML, and the submit button just doesn't work. How do I make the form submit with innerHTML? The form works perfectly when it's in the body, but I need it in the function because I need the picdata data[1].

```
function photoShowcase(picdata){
    var data = picdata.split("|");
    _("picbox").style.display = "block";
    _("picbox").innerHTML += '<div id="contain" style="background: url(\'user/<?php echo $u; ?>/'+data[1]+'\') center no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,.8);">';
    if("<?php echo $isOwner ?>" == "yes"){
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '<div id="deletelink">';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '<form method="POST" action="php_parsers/change_image.php" name="ChangeImage">';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" value="'+data[1]+'" name="file_name" />';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '<input type="submit" value="Set as Profile Picture" name="SetImage" />';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '</form>';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deletePhoto(\''+data[0]+'\')">Delete Photo</a>';
        _("picbox").innerHTML += '</div>';
    }
    _("picbox").innerHTML += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some points:
 
1/ Where is your PHP code?
2/ Where did You call the function? here is the function without any call... You have to call the function with right argument to work..
 
3/ You used (( += )) for first innerHTML...? why is that??? have you used this command before?

I think your answer is in this 3 point.

for more help, please make a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are inserting incomplete html fragments and this is likely to cause the issue.

I would recommend to store the innerHTML in a variable and only append it to the document after it contains all the required closing tags:

```
var htmlString = '<div id="contain" style="background: url(\'user/<?php echo $u; ?>/'+data[1]+'\') center no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,.8);">';
//...
_("picbox").innerHTML += htmlString;
```